# Signing PHP emails on shared hosting

Tags: digital-signature, php, dkim, spf

I am on a shared hosting plan, and when I send emails with PHP, email clients (like [Gmail](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en&ctx=mail)) will add a little `via` bit to my `from` field, with my host's domain in there.

So instead of my emails being just from my domain:

```
From: me@mydomain.com
```

It's from two domains:

```
From: me@mydomain.com via host13.myhost.com
```

Clearly, this is confusing to people receiving email and is poor branding. Since I'm on a shared hosting plan, I don't think I'm likely to have access to the configurations settings of PHP or whatever it uses to mail. Is it possible for me to digitally sign my PHP emails, or is this not possible on shared hosting?

Here is what I'm doing now:

```
$header = "From: me@mydomain.com";
mail("you@yourdomain.com", "subject", "body", $header);
```

Comment: use php mailer via your SMTP

Comment: You should include the code you're using to send the mail. I would say send through a third party, like Gmail itself, and not use `mail()` as it sounds like you might be. You might also look at [SwitfMailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: If you can spare the money, you could look at services such as Amazon SES; they take care of signing, reliable delivery and feedback loops (for bounces and complaints).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, you need to download the PHP Mailer class from [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php4/0.90/) and your code will be like this:

```
 <?php
include "PHP MAILER CLASS";
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    try {
        //$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
        $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $mail->Username   = "example@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
        $mail->Password   = "password";            // GMAIL password
        $mail->AddAddress("Reciever Email", "Reciever Name");
        $mail->SetFrom('Sender Email', 'Sender Name');
        $mail->Subject = "Subject";
        $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
        $mail->MsgHTML("Message Body");
        $mail->Send();
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default mail function is at the mercy of your server setup and rarely looks like regular mail to the reciever.  You should use a library either [SwitfMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [pear MAIL](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) that can send the mail through your own mail server via SMTP.  You can use your normal email account or setup a new one for your web service.